# MySQL double left join returning opposite of expected results

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I am trying to determine who has not yet booked on call on all the saturdays in 2017 between July 1 and December 31.

In MySQL, I have two tables and 1 view:
j3_aqi_userdata_v (view)
j3_sv_apptpro3_requests (table)
j3_oncall_calendar_dates (table)

I need to get a list of all the people from j3_aqi_userdata_v who do not show up in j3_sv_apptpro3_requests.  Simple left join should do it, but not so much. Why, you may ask? Well, I also need to add some statements in the where clause to exclude days which are not saturday, years not in the current year, and months Jan through June.

I have the following, but it's only returning the people who HAVE booked on call:

```
select 
*
from 
j3_aqi_userdata_v t1
    left join (j3_sv_apptpro3_requests t2)
        on (t1.id=t2.user_id)
    left join j3_oncall_calendar_dates t3
        on (t2.startdate=t3.db_date)
where 
t3.saturday_flag = 'T'
and 
t3.year=year(current_date)
and
t3.month >= 7
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Table Structures:

```
j3_aqi_userdata_v
    #   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default     Comments    Extra
    1   id  int(11)             No  0       
    2   author  varchar(400)    utf8mb4_general_ci      No          
    3   username    varchar(150)    utf8mb4_general_ci      No          
    4   email   varchar(100)    utf8mb4_general_ci      No          
    5   employeeid  bigint(21)          No  0       
    6   coach   longtext    utf8mb4_general_ci      Yes     NULL        
    7   geo     longtext    utf8mb4_general_ci      Yes     NULL        
    8   team    longtext    utf8mb4_general_ci      Yes     NULL        
    9   manager     longtext    utf8mb4_general_ci      Yes     NULL        
    10  country     longtext    utf8mb4_general_ci      Yes     NULL    

j3_sv_apptpro3_requests
CREATE TABLE `j3_sv_apptpro3_requests` (
  `id_requests` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `endtime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'new',
  `payment_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'pending',
  `show_on_calendar` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `calendar_comment` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `calendar_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calendar_calendar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cancellation_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txnid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_reminders` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'No',
  `sms_phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_dial_code` varchar(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `google_event_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `google_calendar_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `booking_total` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `booking_deposit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `booking_due` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `coupon_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booked_seats` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `booking_language` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'en-gb',
  `credit_used` float(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `payment_processor_used` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'None',
  `manual_payment_collected` float(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `last_change_operator` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `gift_cert` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `cancel_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `loyalty_points` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out` smallint(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordering` smallint(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `published` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


ALTER TABLE `j3_sv_apptpro3_requests`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_requests`),
  ADD KEY `startdate` (`startdate`);


ALTER TABLE `j3_sv_apptpro3_requests`
  MODIFY `id_requests` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;

j3_oncall_calendar_dates
CREATE TABLE `j3_oncall_calendar_dates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db_date` date NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quarter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day_name` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `dayofweek` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `month_name` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `holiday_flag` char(1) DEFAULT 'F',
  `saturday_flag` char(1) DEFAULT 'T'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `j3_oncall_calendar_dates`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `td_ymd_idx` (`year`,`month`,`day`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `td_dbdate_idx` (`db_date`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Sounds to me LEFT JOIN is converted to a INNER JOIN because off the WHERE statement move the WHERE filter into the ON clause. `ON (t2.startdate=t3.db_date) AND t3.saturday_flag = 'T'....`

Answer (score 0):

Tried that, but it didn't work.  Here's where I ended up and it's working fine now. THanks for the suggestion:

`select 
j3_aqi_userdata_v.author,
j3_aqi_userdata_v.id 
from 
j3_aqi_userdata_v
where
j3_aqi_userdata_v.oncall='Y'
and
 id not IN
(
select user_id from j3_sv_apptpro3_requests
left join j3_oncall_calendar_dates on j3_oncall_calendar_dates.db_date=j3_sv_apptpro3_requests.startdate
where 
j3_oncall_calendar_dates.saturday_flag = 'T'
and 
j3_oncall_calendar_dates.year=year(current_date)
and
j3_oncall_calendar_dates.month >= 7
and j3_sv_apptpro3_requests.resource in ('9','10')
)`